# Deleted tags & categories from my blog still come up in Google search results

Tags: google, google-search-console, web-crawlers, search-engine-indexing, google-index

I am a newbie in blogging. I've deleted some of the unwanted tags and categories from my wordpress blog but they kinda still come put in the search results when I search my website on Google.

How do I get them removed?

Will it be done automatically by the crawler or do I have to manually request re-indexing or something from the Google search console portal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check that those deleted pages are now returning a 404 status. IF so, they should get removed from the index when Google next crawls them. You could use the remove url tool to have them quickly removed, and as long as they 404 they will not come back.

Answer (score 1):

Google search results are not real-time instead they are cached so even if you remove them it won't get removed immediately.

Google will automatically remove them in their own time.

However you try to speed up the process by letting know Google about these by submitting re-indexing or submitting a new sitemap.

Comment: There is no evidence that submitting new sitemap speeds up the de-index process, but you are right on waiting.